# Indefinite integral $\int{3x^2\over (x^3+2)^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question:**

> How to solve this indefinite interal $$\int{3x^2\over (x^3+2)^4}dx$$

**Attempt:**

$3\int x^2{1\over (x^3+2)^4}dx$

Let $u=x^2$ then $du={1\over (x^3+2)^4}dx$.

Am I on the right track or going about it the wrong way?

ok so I make $du=3x^2dx$ but what do I do with this? Does it just disappear?

Comment: If u = $x^2$ then du = 2x dx, or were you starting in integration by parts? Substitution is better.   Might help to note that, if z = $x^3$ then dz = $3x^2$ dx.

Comment: If $u=x^2$ the the substitution $du = 2x dx$ is made, not $du=\frac{1}{(x^3+2)^4}dx$.

Comment: $du$ is what it has to be based on what you let $u$ be (not the rest of the integrand). If $u=x^2$, then $du=2x\,dx$, no good... Try $u=x^3+2$ instead.

Comment: You don't "make" $du=3x^2\,dx$. But you can make $\color{maroon}u=\color{maroon}{x^3+2}$. If you do, then $\color{darkgreen}{du}$ *is* $\color{darkgreen}{3x^2\,dx}$ and $$\int{3x^2\over(x^3+2)^4}\,dx=\int  { \overbrace{\color{darkgreen}{3x^2\,dx}}^{=\color{darkgreen}{du}}\over (\,\underbrace{\color{maroon}{x^3+2}}_{=\color{maroon}u}\,)^4}=\int{1\over u^4}\,du .  $$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Let $u = x^3 + 2$ then $du = 3x^2 dx$ and your integral becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{u^4} du$$

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $u = x^3 +2$ and $\mathrm{d}u = 3x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$ giving $$\int \frac{1}{u^4} \, \mathrm{d}u = -\frac{1}{3u^3} = \bbox[10px, border: solid blue 1px]{-\frac{1}{3(x^3+2)^3} + \mathrm{C}}$$

is much more elegant and tractable than the substitution you proposed.

Comment: Missing the 3 in the denominator sir.

Comment: @Kugelblitz, Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your option $u=x^2$ seems to be a bad one. Indeed, $du=2x\,dx$ doesn't mate very well with the given numerator, and the denominator will turn to the unappetizing $(\sqrt u^3+2)^4$.

It is much more appealing to notice that $3x^2$ is the derivative of $x^3$, so that a substitution $u=x^3$ will yield $du$ at the numerator and $(u+2)^4$ at the denominator, a much more tractable result.